# I want to get the class of a subclass

Tags: python

Can I, in a class that is meant to be subclassed, get the class variable for an instance of its children? Something like this:

```
class A:
    ...
    def doStuff(self):
        c = getChildClass(self)
        setattr(c, 'anAttribute', value)
```

There is some interesting memoization I want to do, and this would make the task so much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the class of the instance itself, use `self.__class__`.

Comment: This will return the subclass and not the superclass?

Comment: It will return the actual class of the object, not the class of the code.

Comment: There's no way to get "the original class containing this function", if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def doStuff(self):
   ...:         c = self.__class__
   ...:         print c, c.__name__
   ...:         setattr(c, 'moo', 'meow')

In [2]: class B(A):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [3]: B().doStuff()
<class '__main__.B'> B

In [4]: B.moo
Out[4]: 'meow'
```

So, `self.__class__` is what you need.